# Panel transparency over different panels

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am a developing a c# app that will be used in a touch computer. It has a secret combination to close it in case something goes wrong. TopRight, TopLeft, TopRight.

To achieve that, I created a class that add two panels to the form:

```
    public enum Location
    {
        Top,
        Bottom
    };
        public SecretCode(Form form, int boxSize, int resetTimer, Location location, bool debug)
    {
        timerReset.Interval = resetTimer;
        timerReset.Tick += TimerReset_Tick;

        Panel panelRight = new Panel();

        if (debug) panelRight.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        panelRight.Size = new Size(boxSize, boxSize);
        panelRight.Location = new Point(form.Width - boxSize, location == Location.Top ? 0 : form.Height - boxSize);
        panelRight.Click += PanelTopRight_Click;

        Panel panelLeft = new Panel();

        if (debug) panelLeft.BackColor = Color.Red;
        panelLeft.Size = new Size(boxSize, boxSize);
        panelLeft.Location = new Point(0, location == Location.Top ? 0 : form.Height - boxSize);
        panelLeft.Click += PanelTopLeft_Click;

        form.Controls.Add(panelRight);
        form.Controls.Add(panelLeft);

        panelLeft.BringToFront();
        panelRight.BringToFront();
    }
```

On my main form, I have different panels (they are all fullscreen) that I show / hide. Every panel has its own background image.

- Panel Intro
- Panel Signup

When the user finishes reading the intro, the whole panel disappears and a the Signup Panel shows up.

Is there any easy way to ensure that the SecretCode panels would always be transparent or do I need to change its parent every time a show a new panel?

Comment: Well, no point in changing the Parent, it is the form.  You just have to make sure that the Z-order is correct so the "secret" is always in front of any other controls.  And that they won't overlap anything.  More BringToFront() calls, perhaps.

Comment: The Secret Panel is already on top of everything, the issue however is that all the panels have a different background image. So the Panels aren't really transparent right now. They are all using gray.

Comment: Then set their BackColor property to Color.Transparent.  That's expensive, making sure that the BackgroundImage is an exact fit with the ClientSize and has the 32bppPArgb pixel format is important.

Comment: That didn't work. Still showing as Grey. From a few other topics i was reading the issue is because the transparent control draw its parent in the background, in this case, as the form is the parent, I get a gray background. I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, assumption was that you were talking about the form's BackgroundImage.  So don't make the form the parent but whatever you overlap.

Comment: No, sorry for the misunderstood. Each panel has its own background image. But what you said might be a good work-around. Change the form background image instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93989/discussion-between-marcelo-and-hans-passant).